# Generate histogram plot for each MFCC coefficient in python

Tags: python-3.x, histogram, librosa, mfcc

How to go about generating the histogram plot in `python` for each of the `MFCC` coefficients extracted from an audio file.  As shown [here](https://www.mathworks.com/help/audio/ref/mfcc.html) from the `Matlab` implementation, a histogram for each MFCC coefficient can be derived:

[image]

How can I go about achieving this same plot in `python`?  I am using `librosa` as the MFCC feature extraction.  Here is my code for the MFCC feature extraction:

```
import librosa
import librosa.display
import numpy as np
import wavio
# Parameters
rate = 44100    # samples per second
T = 1           # sample duration (seconds)
f = 440.0       # sound frequency (Hz)
# Compute waveform samples
t = np.linspace(0, T, T*rate, endpoint=False)
x = np.sin(2*np.pi * f * t)
# Write the samples to a file
wavio.write("sine.wav", x, rate, sampwidth=3)

y, sr = librosa.load('sine.wav')
mfcc_coeff = librosa.feature.mfcc(y=y, sr=sr, n_mfcc=40)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seemed that you didn't require that the sound be a pure sine wave but had just created that to have something to work with, so the below code is just loading in one of `librosa`'s example sounds.

Then the meat of resolving your question is using `pyplot`'s `hist` method on whichever mfcc coefficient you want to look at.

```py
import librosa
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

COEFFICIENT_TO_ANALYZE = 15
N_BINS = 60

y, sr = librosa.load(librosa.ex('brahms'), sr=None)
mfcc_coeff = librosa.feature.mfcc(y=y, sr=sr, n_mfcc=40)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.hist(mfcc_coeff[COEFFICIENT_TO_ANALYZE, :], N_BINS)
ax.set_title(f'MFCC Coefficient {COEFFICIENT_TO_ANALYZE}')
plt.show()
```